# Python - SSLSocket.recv() only returns a single byte

Tags: python

I'm trying to add SSL support for my program. I've used ssl.wrap_socket on non-blocking sockets to create an SSLSocket.

Now I go to read from that socket...

```
try:
    data = sslsock.recv(4096)
except socket.error as e:
    # error
    ...
```

Why do I only receive a single byte? I know that more than 1 byte is available.

When I use this instead...

```
data = ''
while 1:
        try:
            data += self.sock.recv(4096)
        except socket.error as e:
            if data:
                break
            else:
                # error
                ...
```

The full string of bytes are returned. Before using wrap_socket, the full string of bytes were always returned from the recv call.

Comment: Note: I've tried sleeping after the select() call returns and before recv()ing from the socket and it still only returns a single byte. This is happening on both linux and Windows, using python2.7.

Answer (score 1):

`socket.recv` is actually just a wrapper for its *recv(2)* C counterpart.

From the *recv(2)* man page:

> The  receive calls normally return any data available, up to the
>   requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount
>   requested.

Comment: Right, so I'm wondering... why is only 1 byte available every time recv is called on an SSLSocket, while when it's called on a normal socket, there are typically 150 bytes available immediately in my application? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: SSL is a little tricky like that sometimes because of how it's built (I'm not going to go into details here cause that's a pretty long and complicated explanation, especially if your knowledge of SSL is limited). However, the manual clearly states that *"[...] since the SSL (and TLS) protocol has its own framing atop of TCP, the SSL sockets abstraction can, in certain respects, diverge from the specification of normal, OS-level sockets."*.

Comment: i.e.: Available in an OS socket will not necessarily mean available in a SSL socket.

Comment: Certainly. It just seems odd that only 1 byte would ever be available from an SSLSocket.